# file-upload firing twice?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have following code:

.jade:

```
div(layout="row")
    div(layout="column", flex)
        label(style="margin-left: 5px") File
        md-button(class="md-raised", ng-click="onUploadClicked(3)") Upload
        input(id="image3", type="file", accept=".pdf", file-upload="uploadFile”, style="display: none;")
```

.js/controller:

```
$scope.uploadFile = function(file) {
    console.log("upload file");
}

$scope.onUploadImageClicked = function(position) {
    console.log("on upload image");
    $timeout(function() {
        document.querySelector('#image' + (position)).click();
    }, 100);
};
```

The log of `upload file` is printed twice, while `on upload image` is printed once only when I click on the `Upload` button, choose a file from file chooser, press Open button in file chooser.

What could be wrong in my code that makes it fires twice?

**Update:**

Tried to add event.stopPropagation() but no luck

My javascript lists. I only have angular.min.js one.

[image]

Comment: Can verify the number of times angular.js script is loaded ?

Comment: Please see my update @Searching :)

Comment: I have also observed using Network, the `angular.min.js` is only loaded once..

Comment: Can you also post the onUploadClicked function ?

Comment: @AnthonyC please see my update

Comment: @Searching sorry I couldn't understand your question..

Comment: Na..don't worry i got it wrong..I thought binding controller more than once can cause events fire multiple times...

Comment: if you set the #image3 input to be visible and click on it manually, does it still calling the function twice?

Comment: @AnthonyC yup it is..

Comment: Most likely the problem lies within the `file-upload` directive rather than the binding, can you post the `file-upload` directive as well?

Comment: @AnthonyC I don't create the `file-upload`, I think it's the Angular feature..

Comment: The directive would start with `ng-` if it's from angular. are you sure you are not using an other library?

Comment: @AnthonyC oops you are correct lol.. yes I am sure not using other library..

Comment: @AnthonyC LOL you are correct. I found the root cause! I will post the answer..

Answer (score 1):

I found the root cause! Thanks to @AnthonyC to give me a clue.

I have this directive on 2 different javascripts that are loaded in my Jade file:

```
app.directive('fileUpload', ['$parse', function ($parse) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            var onChangeFunc = scope.$eval(attrs.fileUpload);

            element.bind('change', function(){
                onChangeFunc(element[0].files[0]);
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

Ensure there is one directive only in your whole javascripts code!